# what is the different set primary key on model or migration file in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I read the laravel document and I see migration files.
In this file We create tables and columns and we set primary key etc.
For example like this:

```
class CreateAddressesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->string('lng');
            $table->string('lat');
            $table->foreign('company_name')->references('name')->on('companies')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('addresses');
    }
}
```

When I run migrate:install this table add to database with my describes.

But I see this on Eloquent document:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'flight_id';
}
```

What does it mean ?
What happen if I crate table with like migration at first and use model like above ?
my primary key will change?

Comment: Your migration is for a table called `addresses`. What does this have to do with a model called `Flight`? The `$primaryKey` property is for when your database table has a non-standard primary key. Your migration is useless for a model storage since it has no primary key.

Comment: `Flight` is on laravel document. I mean what is the meaning of `$primaryKey` on `Model` is it relation with my table or what?

Comment: It is saying that the primary key on `flights` table is `flight_id` instead of the standard `id`.

Comment: what if I create table with migration file and set another primary key on model, which one is primary key ?

Comment: Migration creates a database table, that is all. It has nothing to do with the model.

Comment: Laravel uses a convention that primary key on a table is named `id` if you use any other name for primary key say 'user_id' as the name of primary key column then in the User model you specify `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id'` which will instruct laravel to use `user_id` as primary key say when you do `$user = User::find(25)`